# Stop tauri application from reloading after changes

Tags: rust, tauri

I am in the midst of writing an Tauri application which displays an image which is being modified at runtime. (I either write a new image and change the path or rewrite the image itself). Problem is that every time i change the image the whole application refreshes. That is probably a nice feature in 99% of cases, but for me it makes the programming process nearly impossible. Is there some way to turn that off?

Comment: Try running tauri with the `--no-watch` flag (i.e. `cargo tauri dev --no-watch`)

Comment: you can completely disable the watcher by using the `--no-dev-watcher` flag when running `tauri dev`. Alternatively you can create a `.taurignore` file next to your `tauri.conf.json` file in which you can tell tauri to ignore the path of your image similar to how .gitignore files work.

Comment: ty guys that sloved it for me =)